# Facebook like button offset beneath div even though there's no margin or padding

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

As you can see from the example below, the Facebook like button is supposed to appear in that blank space between the date and the start of the article, but instead it's shifted downwards for an unknown reason that I can't figure out. I'm sure it's some obscure weird CSS stuff, but any help is appreciated. Thanks! :-)

And here's the actual page: http://readabout.me/achievements/Reinhardt-University-s-Morgan-Sparks-Selected-for-Who-s-Who-Among-Students-in-American-Universities-and-Colleges/3638644

[image: Exapmple]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fount the issue

Please remove margin #news-story iframe.fb_ltr

http://readabout.me/stylesheets/news.css  line 30 - and set padding top on "#fbLikeButton" problem will be solve

[I could fixed the issue on firebugg , this is print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuKqJ.gif);

Comment: This can overlapped with the !important property also.

Comment: Yes, by removing the margin you can see the difference, but i think that this is not correct, it just needs to add a height property in the like button - #fbLikeButton{height:60px;}

Comment: yes height property is also good solution , Avoid maximum margin property because margin is not a good property in IE

Answer (score 2):

Delete line 30 in your news.css file:

```
#news-story iframe.fb_ltr {margin:25px 0 10px 0;}
```

You are explicitly giving the like button iframe a top margin of 25px.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem :)

```
<div id="fbLikeButton" style="height: 50px; ">
```

Edit: I think the @cpilko has spotted the exact reason, though I believe the news.css is not yours but facebook's, in that case you can try adding the following code to your css.

```
#news-story iframe.fb_ltr {
 margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a height property in the like button - `#fbLikeButton{height:60px;}`

Answer (score 0):

This worked. Thanks everyone!

```
-#news-story iframe.fb_ltr {margin:25px 0 10px 0;}
+
+div#fbLikeButton {
+    margin-top: 10px;
+    margin-bottom: 10px;
+}
```

Basically, I removed the internal styling and styled the surrounding div. I didn't realize we had code that actually styled inside the Facebook like button iFrame.